# foreach() loop error in R

Tags: r, foreach, xts

The following `for()` loop takes in each character name from `NAME` and extracts and formats (from `crsp1`) into `xts()` which is then saved into `DATA`:

```
 DATA <- xts()

system.time(
  for (i in 1:dim(NAMES)[2]){
  nudata <- crsp1[which(crsp1[,1]== paste(NAMES[1,i])),]
  z = xts(coredata(nudata[,c(2)]), order.by= round(as.POSIXct(nudata[,7], format="%y-%m-%d"),      
  units=c("days")))
  colnames(z) <- NAMES[1,i]
  DATA <- merge.xts(DATA,z, join="outer")
 }  
 )
```

The code takes approximately 239.21 seconds. I believe the `for()` loop can be improved but I cannot figure out how exactly. I have looked into `library(doParallel)` and came up with the following:

```
# turned my code into a function: `CRISP`
CRISP  = function(i) {
nudata <- crsp1[which(crsp1[,1]== paste(NAMES[1,i])),]
z = xts(coredata(nudata[,c(2)]), order.by= round(as.POSIXct(nudata[,7], format="%y-%m-%d"),   
units=c("days")))
colnames(z) <- NAMES[1,i]
DATA <- merge.xts(DATA,z, join="outer")
}
```

Then I ran using `foreach()`

```
# install packages and register cores first
install.packages("doParallel")
library("doParallel")
cl <- makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(cl)

# run in Parallel
DATA <- xts()
system.time(
foreach (i = 1:dim(NAMES)[2], .packages='xts') %dopar% CRISP(i)
)
```

however, after approximately 70 seconds the following error is printed:

```
Error in CRISP(i) : task 1 failed - "object 'DATA' not found"
```

I do not understand why `DATA` is not found?

## REPRODUCIBLE SAMPLE DATA

NAMES:

```
NAMES <- structure(list(X1 = structure(1L, .Label = "AMERICAN CAR & FDRY CO", class = "factor"), 
X2 = structure(1L, .Label = "ALASKA JUNEAU GOLD MNG CO", class = "factor"), 
X3 = structure(1L, .Label = "AMERICAN SAFETY RAZOR CORP", class = "factor"), 
X4 = structure(1L, .Label = "AMERICAN BRAKE SHOE & FDRY", class = "factor"), 
X5 = structure(1L, .Label = "ABITIBI POWER & PAPER LTD", class = "factor")), .Names = c("X1", 
"X2", "X3", "X4", "X5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

crsp1:

```
crsp1 <- list(COMNAM = c(31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2), RET = c(45553, 22625, 31216, 2897, 21995, 21995, 45553, 18171, 
21995, 36821, 14301, 14530, 45553, 24793, 1409, 35194, 32919, 
30210, 45553, 1, 26123, 4148, 26123, 40785, 45553, 6063, 29673, 
9213, 26222, 28048), RETX = c(45262, 22610, 31102, 2875, 21989, 
21989, 45262, 18164, 21989, 36626, 14281, 14511, 45262, 24761, 
1393, 35018, 32778, 30102, 45262, 1, 26076, 4118, 26076, 40534, 
45262, 6028, 29576, 9177, 26173, 27972), vwretd = c(NA, 0.005893, 
0.001277, -0.003984, -0.000172, 0.007211, 0.001277, -0.003984, 
-0.000172, 0.007211, -0.000804, 0.003384, NA, 0.005893, 0.001277, 
-0.003984, -0.000172, 0.007211, NA, 0.005893, 0.001277, -0.003984, 
-0.000172, 0.007211, NA, 0.005893, 0.001277, -0.003984, -0.000172, 
0.007211), ewretd = c(NA, 0.009516, 0.00578, -0.001927, 0.001182, 
0.008453, 0.00578, -0.001927, 0.001182, 0.008453, -0.001689, 
0.003312, NA, 0.009516, 0.00578, -0.001927, 0.001182, 0.008453, 
NA, 0.009516, 0.00578, -0.001927, 0.001182, 0.008453, NA, 0.009516, 
0.00578, -0.001927, 0.001182, 0.008453), sprtrn = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), DATE = c(-16072, 
-16070, -16068, -16067, -16066, -16065, -16068, -16067, -16066, 
-16065, -16064, -16063, -16072, -16070, -16068, -16067, -16066, 
-16065, -16072, -16070, -16068, -16067, -16066, -16065, -16072, 
-16070, -16068, -16067, -16066, -16065))
```

Comment: Probably `DATA` doesn't exist in the workspace of each node.

Comment: would i have to call it each time as the `.packages` ? @Pascal

Comment: I am not a specialist of `foreach` package, but probably `.import` will be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem hasn't parallel solution, because you add z to a data in parallel.
I suggest you first calculate all z and then merge them with data after the foreach.
foreach can return result.

```
CRISP  = function(i) {
nudata <- crsp1[which(crsp1[,1]== paste(NAMES[1,i])),]
z = xts(coredata(nudata[,c(2)]), order.by= round(as.POSIXct(nudata[,7], format="%y-%m-%d"),   
units=c("days")))
colnames(z) <- NAMES[1,i]
return (z) #DATA <- merge.xts(DATA,z, join="outer")
}
```

and

```
system.time(
all_z=foreach (i = 1:dim(NAMES)[2], .packages='xts') %dopar% return(CRISP(i))
)
```

then merge all_z with data

Comment: thanks for your input. How/where can I save the calculated z's of each iteration so I can merge them later  ?

Comment: if it was helpful please reputation by accept the answer or raise the answer. i need reputation to ask my question by image.

Comment: thanks for the code. It is quite was I was looking for but it returns a list. how do i return it into a merged `xts()` object.

Comment: Thanks @parvij I tweeked it a bit to get desired output. `all_z <- foreach (i = 1:dim(NAMES)[2],.combine='merge.xts' ,.packages='xts') %dopar% {return(CRISP(i))}`